# MSVC: C++14: std:set: comparison function: why "const" is required?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, const-correctness, stdset

Sample code:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class x
{
private:
  int i;
public:
  int get_i() const { return i; }
};

struct x_cmp
{
    bool operator()(x const & m1, x const & m2)
#if _MSC_VER
    const
#endif
    {
        return m1.get_i() > m2.get_i();
    }
};

std::set<x, x_cmp> members;

void add_member(x const & member)
{
    members.insert(member);
}
```

Invocations:

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
$ clang++ -c -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
$ icc -c -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra
<nothing>
$ cl /c /std:c++14 /Za
<nothing>
```

Question: why msvc requires `const` while others don't? Or why others don't require `const`?

Comment: MSVC is correct. Your operator should be marked const because it is being used on a const object, and should be marked as such because it does not (_should not_) modify the object anyway. Turn up your warnings on the other compilers and they’ll complain too.

Comment: @Dúthomhas With warnings turned on they don't complain: https://godbolt.org/z/4dhMjYW56. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [LWG2542](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2542). In C++14, the wording for the comparison operator said "possibly const", which was interpreted by GCC and Clang as meaning that the comparison operator was not required to be `const` qualified. MSVC always required it.

This is a wording defect, as comparison operators for associative containers should be `const` qualified. This was changed in C++17 to require the comparator to be `const`. This is a breaking change, so valid (though broken) C++14 code may fail to compile in C++17.