# static assertion failed: comparison object must be invocable as const when using my custom comparison function in set container

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, constants, comparison

I'm confused about this. When I am using a set and trying to use my custom comparison function, it shows:

```
C:/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tree.h:457:21: error: static assertion failed: comparison object must be invocable as const
   static_assert(is_invocable_v<const _Compare&, const _Key&, const _Key&>,
```

My code is like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class mycomp{
public:
    bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b){
        return a > b;
    }
};
int main(){
    set<int, mycomp> test;
    test.insert(4);
    test.insert(5);
    test.insert(2);
    test.insert(1);
    test.insert(3);

}
```

I don't know why I have to add a `const` after the comparison function like this `bool operator()(const int& a, const int& b) const{}`.

Comment: Because the compare function must be able to be called with a const instance.

Comment: @康桓瑋 thank you! It solved my question!

Comment: Answer is here:
[MSVC: C++14: std:set: comparison function: why "const" is required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975761/msvc-c14-stdset-comparison-function-why-const-is-required)